# Where condition in SQl to filter the second part of string to be an integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

My requirement is to select records in SQL which is in the below format,
"Hello-12345"
I tried with,
select name from vend
WHERE name LIKE 'Hello-%'
But this query is returning records as follows,
"Hello-123abc"
Here i will have to make sure that the second section after "Hello-" should be definitely numeric only. Kindly help.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
WHERE name LIKE 'Hello-[0-9]%' AND SUBSTRING(name,7,8000) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally. The regex is 'Hello-[^a-zA-Z]%[0-9]'. Thanks :)

Comment: That will match `Hello-1xxx7`

Answer (score 0):

Use substring get the second part of hello-* world and use isnumeric function to check the second part is numeric or not.

```
Isnumeric(Substring(expression, 7,  len(expression) - 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
WHERE name LIKE 'Hello-[0-9]%' AND name NOT LIKE 'Hello-%[^0-9]%'
```